# How to convert a dataframe to ndarray of 0s and 1s?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
col_1 col_2
a     4
a     3
b     2
c     2
d     1
b     4
c     1
```

I need to transform it into a NumPy array of 2D-arrays where each 2D-array corresponds to one of the letters. For example, if 'a' doesn't occur together with 1 and 2, and occurs with 3 and 4, 2D array corresponding to it should look like `[0, 0, 1, 1]`. So in this example I need:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way `crosstab`

```
l = pd.crosstab(df.col_1,df.col_2).values.tolist()
Out[23]: [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```